# Right Join not returning all expected rows

Tags: sql

I have two queries which I am running in HP ALM (formally Quality Center):

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
TEST.TS_NAME
FROM CYCLE
JOIN TESTCYCL ON (TESTCYCL.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID)
JOIN TEST ON TEST.TS_TEST_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID)
WHERE CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = 44451
```

This returns 38 rows with all the test names I want to report on.

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
STEP.ST_RUN_ID as "RunId" /*Test Step.Run No*/ ,
TEST.TS_NAME as "Test Name",
STEP.ST_STATUS as "Run Status",
STEP.ST_STEP_NAME as "Step Name",
CYCLE.CY_CYCLE as "TestSet",
CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_NAME  as "Test Lab Folder Name"
FROM RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, TEST
WHERE RUN.RN_CYCLE_ID = CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID
AND CYCLE.CY_FOLDER_ID = CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_ID
AND CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = 44451
AND STEP.ST_RUN_ID = RUN.RN_RUN_ID
AND RUN.RN_TEST_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID
AND RUN.RN_RUN_ID in (select MAX(RUN.RN_RUN_ID) FROM RUN
GROUP BY RN_TESTCYCLE_ID)
```

This query returns all of the tests with the individual steps and their status. The MAX statement returns the latest run of that test.

When a test is run, a RUN_ID is assigned in the STEP table. The issue is that if a test has not been run, it won't have a RUN_ID and therefore won't be included in the results.

So I created the below query 3:

```
SELECT
STEP.ST_RUN_ID as "RunId" /*Test Step.Run No*/,
TEST.TS_NAME as "Test Name",
STEP.ST_STATUS as "Run Status",
STEP.ST_STEP_NAME as "Step Name",
CYCLE.CY_CYCLE as "TestSet",
CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_NAME  as "Test Lab Folder Name" 
FROM RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, TEST
    RIGHT JOIN (
          SELECT 
          TEST.TS_NAME
          FROM CYCLE
          JOIN TESTCYCL ON (TESTCYCL.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID)
          JOIN TEST ON TEST.TS_TEST_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID)
          WHERE CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = 44451) alltest 
          ON alltest.TS_NAME = TEST.TS_NAME
WHERE RUN.RN_CYCLE_ID = CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID
AND CYCLE.CY_FOLDER_ID = CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_ID
AND STEP.ST_RUN_ID = RUN.RN_RUN_ID
AND RUN.RN_TEST_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID
AND RUN.RN_RUN_ID in (select MAX(RUN.RN_RUN_ID) FROM RUN GROUP BY rn_testcycl_id)
```

I wanted to RIGHT JOIN on all the tests and populate the rows which have a run recorded but it's still not returning the NULL rows. There is no difference between running query 2 or 3.

Comment: Do you understand that comma has lower precedence than keyword joins so that query means FROM RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, (TEST RIGHT JOIN () ON c) WHERE d. But that WHERE makes this the same as FROM RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, (TEST INNER JOIN () ON c) WHERE d. Which is the same as FROM RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, TEST, () WHERE c AND d. Which is the same as FROM (RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, TEST) INNER JOIN () ON c WHERE d. But that WHERE makes this the same as FROM (RUN, CYCL_FOLD, CYCLE, STEP, TEST) RIGHT JOIN () ON c WHERE d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not returning the rows because the `where` clause is filtering them out.

Use ANSI standard `join` syntax (an `on` clause) and put the conditions in the `on` clause.  The result is something like this:

```
SELECT s.ST_RUN_ID as "RunId" /*Test Step.Run No*/, t.TS_NAME as "Test Name",
       s.ST_STATUS as "Run Status", s.ST_STEP_NAME as "Step Name", c.CY_CYCLE as "TestSet",
       cf.CF_ITEM_NAME  as "Test Lab Folder Name" 
FROM RUN r join
     CYCL_FOLD cf
     on c.RN_CYCLE_ID = cf.CY_CYCLE_ID join
     CYCLE c
     on c.CY_FOLDER_ID = cf.CF_ITEM_ID join
     STEP s
     on s.ST_RUN_ID = r.RN_RUN_ID join
     TEST t
     on r.RN_TEST_ID = t.TS_TEST_ID right join
     (SELECT TEST.TS_NAME
      FROM CYCLE JOIN
           TESTCYCL
           ON TESTCYCL.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID JOIN
           TEST
           ON TEST.TS_TEST_ID = TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID
      WHERE CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = 44451
     ) alltest 
     ON alltest.TS_NAME = t.TS_NAME and
        r.RN_RUN_ID in (select MAX(RUN.RN_RUN_ID) FROM RUN GROUP BY rn_testcycl_id);
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to get the null values do the right outer join, instead of right join..

Comment: Thanks for replying but I tried this but it just returned the same results

Comment: isnt right outer join and right join the same thing?