# Right outer join with where clause not returning expected results

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join, right-join

I have a SQL statement that works perfectly:

```
SELECT 
    DailyRequest.*
FROM 
    DailyRequest
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Facilities ON FacilityID = Facilities.ID
```

This shows all the records in `Facilities`, as expected. However, I need to show only the records for a specified date, but still all of them from Facilities. I thought the SQL below would work, but it does not.

This SQL only shows the records from `DailyRequest`:

```
SELECT 
    DailyRequest.*
FROM
    DailyRequest
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Facilities ON FacilityID = Facilities.ID 
WHERE 
    RequestDate = '7/21/2021'
```

The date seems to introduce the problem, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I want to show all the records from the joined tables, even if they don't exist in `DailyRequest`.

Comment: Switch the order of the tables.  Use `LEFT JOIN`.  And move the condition to the `ON` clause.

Comment: . . Your query as written doesn't really make sense.  I don't see why you would want to return rows that are entirely `NULL` where there is no match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right Join not returning all expected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784519/right-join-not-returning-all-expected-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to apply the date limitation in the join itself for it to properly effect results. Try:

```
SELECT 
DailyRequest.*
    from DailyRequest
        right outer join Facilities on FacilityID = Facilities.ID 
            and DailyRequest.RequestDate = '7/21/2021'
```