# How can I use a subquery to select entries based on highest values in multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, select, subquery

How do I select a database entry who has the highest value in multiple columns? (PostgreSQL)

I have a horse racing database and two tables I joined together in this statement. Then I sorted the values I want by a WHERE statement. Now I want to SELECT only the entries with the highest value in multiple, specified columns:

**I want to select only entries that have the highest lastrace_rating and highest going_rating - if no horse is highest ranked in both categories in this race, I want no response / empty response (does not matter)**

So there can only be one Selection per race

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT h.racename, h.racetime, h.racedate, h.odds, h.pos
FROM horse_ratings hr
RIGHT JOIN horses h ON hr.daily_racename = h.racename
  AND hr.daily_racedate = h.racedate
  AND hr.daily_racetime = h.racetime
  AND hr.dailyhorsename = h.horsename
WHERE 
  hr.daily_racedate = '2023-04-13'
  AND hr.daily_racename = 'Staropramen Zero Alcohol Handicap'
  AND hr.daily_racetime = '4:15'
  AND final_horse_rating > 0
  AND h.odds > 0
  AND hr.dailyhorsename IS NOT NULL 
  AND hr.lastrace_rating = (SELECT MAX(lastrace_rating) FROM horse_ratings)
  AND hr.going_rating = (SELECT MAX(going_rating) FROM horse_ratings);
```

But it does not work - even if I reduce it to one condition (going_rating), I get no response - although the values are there(Just testet with sorting by ORDER BY lastrace_rating DESC). Tried some variations like

```
  AND (hr.lastrace_rating, hr.going_rating) IN (
    SELECT MAX(lastrace_rating), MAX(going_rating)
    FROM horse_ratings
```

But I think I am on the wrong path here.

How do I Select entries based on if they have the highest value in multiple columns in PostgreSQL?
I searched, but could not find an answer.

*Edit*

Basicly, from this table, I want to select the horse 'Little Tiger', because he has the highest values in both 'lastrace_rating' and 'going_rating'

This is the layout for the table horse_ratings:

| daily_racedate | daily_racetime | dailytrack | dailyracename | dailyhorsename | lastrace_rating | final_horse_rating | going_rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Bailar Contigo | 76 | 80 | 52 |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Petite Sioux | 65 | 67 | 50 |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Little Tiger | 80 | 75 | 90 |

The table "horses" has this layout:

| racetime | racedate | track | racename | horsename | pos | odds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Bailar Contigo | 3 | 5 |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Petite Sioux | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-05-23 | 05:15:00 | Wolverhampton | At The Races App Handicap | Little Tiger | 2 | 19 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right Join not returning all expected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784519/right-join-not-returning-all-expected-rows)

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Comment: A scalar subquery must return a 1x1 table. What if 2 rows have the max value? Use DISTINCT or IN.

Comment: Please update the question with at least sample data and expected results. The table DDL would also be useful. In the posted query a reference is made to `final_horse_rating`, but it's lacking a qualifier, so it's impossible for us to know which table has that column.

Comment: None of the rows in your example dataset match the WHERE conditions, so of course no rows are returned.

Comment: Please clairify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Pllease act on the feedback. PS Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" description that doesn't precede or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "it is false that".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.daily_time, t.daily_date, t.daily_location, t.daily_name, t.value1, t.value2
FROM (
    SELECT daily_time, daily_date, daily_location, daily_name,value1, value2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY daily_time, daily_date, daily_location
                              ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC) AS rn,
           LEAD(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY daily_time, daily_date, daily_location
                              ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC) AS next_rating2
    FROM test
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND t.next_rating2 <= t.value2;
```

This has different column names than the example above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question or comments when `final_horse_rating` is to be used, so the following query ignores that column; however, it does address selecting only horses from each race that have the highest rating in both `lastrace_rating` and `going_rating`.

```
WITH horse_ratings(daily_racedate, daily_racetime, dailytrack, daily_racename, daily_horsename, lastrace_rating,
                   final_horse_rating, going_rating) AS
       (VALUES ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Bailar Contigo',
                76, 80, 52),
               ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Petite Sioux', 65,
                67, 50),
               ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Little Tiger', 80,
                75, 90)),
     horses(racedate, racetime, track, racename, horsename, pos, odds) AS
       (VALUES ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Bailar Contigo', 3,
                5),
               ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Petite Sioux', 1,
                3),
               ('2023-05-23'::date, '05:15:00'::time, 'Wolverhampton', 'At The Races App Handicap', 'Little Tiger', 2,
                19)),
     max_race_ratings AS (SELECT daily_racename,
                                 daily_racedate,
                                 daily_racetime,
                                 MAX(lastrace_rating) AS max_lastrace_rating,
                                 MAX(going_rating)    AS max_going_rating
                            FROM horse_ratings
                            GROUP BY daily_racename, daily_racedate, daily_racetime)
SELECT h.horsename, h.racename, h.racetime, h.racedate, h.odds, h.pos
  FROM horse_ratings hr
    JOIN max_race_ratings mrr
         ON (hr.daily_racename = mrr.daily_racename AND
             hr.daily_racedate = mrr.daily_racedate AND
             hr.daily_racetime = mrr.daily_racetime AND
             hr.lastrace_rating = mrr.max_lastrace_rating AND
             hr.going_rating = mrr.max_going_rating)
    JOIN horses h
         ON (hr.daily_racename = h.racename AND
             hr.daily_racedate = h.racedate AND
             hr.daily_racetime = h.racetime AND
             hr.daily_horsename = h.horsename);
```